# fixed math library >Q16

Tags: c, math, embedded, fixed

I'm searching for an basic fixed math library that support bigger numbers then Q16. Rewriting a lib like libfixmath to Q32, isn't option because my embedded C compiler doesn't support int64. For bigger values I have to split the exponent and fraction. Only, I don't know how to mul and div really fast with a split exponent and fraction.

hope you have a suggestion.

Tanks.

Comment: Take a look at AFP - Arbitrary Fixed Point library. Althogh it is written in another language, it will be clear to you how mul and div are actually simple integer math. Speed improvement is easy with fixed number of bits for fractional part (multiples of 8, 16 or 32). I have done very fast optimized s31.32 for one commercial AVR compiler, and all info you need for implementation is in this project: http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?module=Freaks%20Academy&func=viewItem&item_type=project&item_id=2351